# Using Applescript To Adjust Colors In Preview

Tags: xcode, applescript

I'm very new to Applescripts.

**My Goal**: Automatically open (in one window/instance) all of the pictures located within a directory using the "Preview" application, access the "Adjust Colors" toolbox [Tools > Adjust Colors...], click the "Auto Level" button said toolbox, proceed to the next image and click "Auto Level", etc. , and Save All.

I've been using the Xcode "Accessibility Inspector" utility in an attempt to get the names and classes of these buttons and such, but I am also new to using the Accessibility Inspector, so I'm mostly playing at this point.

So far, this is my hodgepodge of an Applescript; Having done some crude assembling of some snippets of others' Applescripts, I've been able to open the pictures with only partial repeatable success:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    open folder "Import" of folder "Shared" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    set pics to select every item of folder "Import" of folder "Shared" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    open pics
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell Application "Preview"
    click menu item "Adjust Color..." of menu bar item "Tools" of window 1
end tell
```

I understand that there are just so....so many things that would make your grandmother cringe about this code, but I was hoping to break it down...

1. I am not sure how to open all of the images in one window. The [open pics] line seems to open each file separately, even though they've all been selected.
2. Applescripts doesn't seem to like the fact that I'm telling an Application to click a menu item. But I don't think Preview constitutes a "Process" (i.e. changing "tell application"... to "tell process".. allows the code to compile, but the process "Preview" doesn't exist... oi!
3. Looking forward to the point when I can start telling it to click the "Auto Level" button in the toolbox, what might be the class (?) of the toolbox? I see "floating window" in the Accessibility Inspector, but errors have been thrown at my attempts...

Thank you for any insight, resources, or pep talks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI scripting especially Preview.app is a real pain.

Please try this, it opens the images one by one, clicks the `Auto Level` button saves the image and close it.

Make sure that the floating window `Adjust Color` is not opened before running the script. If the script gets stuck, close the floating window, quit preview and run the script again.

```
set sharedFolder to path to shared documents folder
tell application "Finder" to set allImages to every item of folder "Import" of sharedFolder

set adjustColorWindow to missing value
repeat with anImage in allImages
    tell application "Finder" to open anImage
    activate application "Preview"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Preview"
            repeat until exists (1st window whose value of attribute "AXSubRole" is "AXStandardWindow")
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            set documentWindow to (name of 1st window whose value of attribute "AXSubRole" is "AXStandardWindow")
            if adjustColorWindow is missing value then
                click menu item "Adjust Color…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Tools" of menu bar 1
                repeat until exists (1st window whose title starts with "Adjust Color")
                    delay 0.2
                end repeat
            end if
            set adjustColorWindow to (1st window whose title starts with "Adjust Color")
            tell adjustColorWindow
                click button "Auto Levels"
            end tell
            click menu item "Save" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
            click button 1 of window documentWindow
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Building strongly on ***vadian***'s answer, I'd delete the `activate application "Preview"` line. For me it interferes when first starting up Preview and when opening picture after picture. Make sure, preview is your standard application for opening picture files and it shoud work fine. Also for other ppl interested, I worked out on how to manipulate the sliders. When working with pictures that have a large file size, preview seems to become unstable so working with delays can help. Following is the altered vode from ***vadian*** for a folder on your desktop, containing pictures. Just change `*Username*` and create a Folder (here named `APPLESCRIPT`) on your desktop:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set desktopFolder to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:*Username*:Desktop"
    set allImages to every item of folder "APPLESCRIPT" of desktopFolder
end tell

set adjustColorWindow to missing value
repeat with anImage in allImages
    delay 5.0
    tell application "Finder" to open anImage
    -- activate application "Preview"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Preview"
            repeat until exists (1st window whose value of attribute "AXSubRole" is "AXStandardWindow")
                delay 1.0
            end repeat
            set documentWindow to (name of 1st window whose value of attribute "AXSubRole" is "AXStandardWindow")
            if adjustColorWindow is missing value then
                click menu item "Adjust Color ..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "Tools" of menu bar 1
                repeat until exists (1st window whose title starts with "Adjust Color")
                    delay 1.0
                end repeat
            end if
            set adjustColorWindow to (1st window whose title starts with "Adjust Color")
            tell adjustColorWindow

                -- click button "Auto Levels"
                -- get value of slider x
                -- slider 1: exposure (-2.0; 2.0)
                -- slider 2: contrast (-1.0; 1.0)
                -- slider 3: highlights (-1.0; -0.3)
                -- slider 4: shadows (0.0; 1.0)
                -- slider 5: saturation (0.0; 2.0)
                -- slider 6: temperature (3500.0; 6500.0)
                -- slider 7: hue (-150.0; 150.0)
                -- slider 8: eepia (0.0; 1.0)
                -- slider 9: sharpness (-1.0; 1.0)

                set value of slider 1 to 2.0
                delay 3.0

                set value of slider 6 to 3500.0
                delay 3.0

                set value of slider 9 to 1.0
                delay 3.0

                set value of slider 2 to -0.95
                delay 3.0

            end tell
        end tell

        tell application "Preview" to close every window

    end tell
end repeat
tell application "System Events" to quit application "Preview"
```